# R - Aggregate data in dataframe by creating groups "1:10" and "11 or more"

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I am adding an auxiliary column to lately group a serie of data in different categories:

```
  for (i in 1:nrow(A) ) {

    if (A$B[i] < 11) {
      A$C[i] <- A$B[i]
    } else {
      A$C[i] <- "11 or more"
    }
  }
```

B is a serie of numeric values [1,2,3,4,5...n]. After the previous code is executed, I can simplify the dataframe to just 11 rows (1:10 and "11 or more") using aggregate:

```
aggregate(. ~ C, data=A, FUN=sum)
```

I am totally sure, I could achieve the same directly, that means, without having to use an auxiliary column. Any hint of function or library?

Comment: use vectorized `ifelse` `A$C<-with (A, ifelse(B<11,B,"11 or more"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Does this do what you want?
aggregate(. ~ pmin(B, 11), data = A, FUN = sum)
```

Comment: I will need to transform "group 11" into "group 11 or more", but I could do it with JavaScript (I am sending the output as a json file and showing it in a webpage). Not only I don't have to use the aux column, but your solution "magically" orders my dataframe from 1 to 11, which is optimal for the output as JSON file.

Answer (score 2):

this should do it `A$C <- ifelse(A$B < 11, as.character(A$B), "11 or more")`
Plus it's vectorized.

Comment: Maybe I explain wrong, but with your option I still have to use aggregate() to simplify my dataframe. However, an upvote for showing me a more optimal way to use the if statement for this case!